# Rails Favorite_posts: "Couldn't find Post with an ID"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, activerecord

BLUF: Trying to make a Favorite_posts feature; I can verify that it works by manually setting the ActiveRecord in the Rails console,

But the links I made give the error: **"Couldn't find Post without an ID"**

The Form:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <% unless current_user.favorite_posts.exists?(id: @post.id) %>
    <%= link_to favorite_posts_path(post_id: @post), method: :post do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to favorite_post_path(@post), method: :delete do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The Controller:

```
class FavoritePostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, :set_post

  def create
    Favorite.create(favorited: @post, user: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Favorite.where(favorited_id: @post.id, user_id: current_user.id).first.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id] || params[:id])
  end

end
```

The Models:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :favorited, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord

    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name

    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, source: :favorited, source_type: 'Post'
```

The Routes:

```
  resources :users do
    collection do
      match 'search' => 'users#index_gyms', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
    end

    member do
      get :following, :followers
      get :favorite_posts
    end
  end

  resources :favorite_posts,      only: [:create, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: I had refactored out this form from a _post partial item, and it worked fine when I  put it back in. I think the back end was only set up for that one controller, and I  don't care enough to refactor it out properly

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing @post.id instead of @post to your url,

```
favorite_posts_path(id: @post.id)
```

Comment: I have; still the same result.

Comment: I have; still the same result. I think there's problem with the `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id] || params[:id])`

Comment: but i don't knwo enough on how to fix it